# Reading int from a .csv file with fscanf function

Tags: c, file, csv, scanf

I'm trying to read some integers from a `.csv` file. I don't know exactly how many integers are in the file in each line, i just know that all the `csv` file is something like:

```
1,2,3,9,6,3,4
4,5,6,7
2,3,8,9,4
```

I need to store every line in an array, but I don't know how can I read integers values from a file without knowing how many integers are in the line.
In my program I have to check if every line have just 2 elements and if the second element is equal to the sel value I receive from the main.

```
 void fun1 (sel)
{
    int aux[3];
    int res;
    FILE* fp;


    fd=fopen("c:\\myfile.csv","r");
    if(fd==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(!feof(fd))
    {
        res=fscanf(fd,"%d,%d,%d",&aux[0],&aux[1],&aux[2]);

        if(res==2&&aux[1]==sel)
        {

            puts("Value ok");
        }

    }
    }
```

I've tried to put `3 %d` in the `fscanf` because if the line contains more then 2 elements I'm sure I don't need that line, but if the line contains more then 3 elements the program keep running without do anything.

I think the problem appear because the `fscanf` function stop when reach a `'\n'` , but how can I fix the code if I don't know how many elements contains each line of the `.csv` file?

Comment: Try using fgetc to read a character at a time.  What's your plan to hold the values in your array when the line has 6 or 7 values.

Comment: Consider using [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read an entire line. Then use [`strtok`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)+[`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or [`sscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) in a loop to parse out the numbers.

Comment: Your array where you store the integers also needs to be either a) large enough to hold the most integers on a line you're willing to support, or b) dynamically allocated, e.g. with `malloc`.

Comment: I only need to hold the first 2 values when there are only 2 values, if there are more then 2 values i don't need the line

Comment: Even if you don't need the rest of the line you still need to read it so that you can get to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with kalum. I think you are on the right track with your solution but I would do something with `fgets` to loop around the lines in the file:

```
#define MAX_LINE (256)

void function(int sel){
    char line[MAX_LINE+1];
    int aux[3];

    int count;
    fd = fopen("foo.csv","r");
    while(fgets(line,MAX_LINE,fd)){
        count = sscanf(line,"%d,%d,%d",aux[0],aux[1],aux[2]);
        if(count == 2 && aux[1] == sel){
            print("ok");
        }
        /* Do we need to store data here? */
    }
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Now there are assumptions built into this, like assumptions about `MAX_LINE`
and and your arrays and how many lines might be in your file and what types of int your are talking about.  What kinds of white space do you need to worry about? What happens when you read a partial line?

Lines might have 1000 leading spaces, or tabs and form feeds.  How big can the integers be?  Are the integers signed?  Is `%d` big enough on your platform and your numbers...`uint8`, `uint16`..... Do you have to make this work on many platforms?  Each one of those details may tweak the solution around.

What is probably the "hard" issue with your question is that you say you need to store the data in an array. Once you say that the problem changes because now you need to know how many lines are in the file before you process it. In C dealing with arbitrary size is a bit of a pain as you either

1. Guess big (static size) and error out sometimes.
2. Scan through the file and incrementally allocate memory.
3. Scan through the whole file once to find the number of array elements to allocate and a second time to fill the array.

Comment: `aux[1] = sel` is assignment, not compare.